# onContextItemSelected method for a table row

Tags: android, row, android-tablelayout

I am creating an activity which contains one table. When selecting a row, I want to update or delete the row through context menu options.
The table is within TableLayout view. Each row is added to the TableLayout as a TableRow view, and also for each TableRow I registered it for context menu with registerForContextMenu(tr);

The context menu options are displayed when selecting a row, but the problem is that I need the number of the selected row. I thought that this could be achieved with the following source code in the onContextItemSelected( MenuItem item ) method : ?

```
   AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();  
   int selectedRow = (int) info.id;
```

but the AdapterContextMenuInfo is always null.

Could I achieve the table row by other method?

Comment: This won't work. Use a ListActivity/ListView.

Answer (score 1):

Still searching for an answer for this to see if there's a better way, but when you create your table row, you can set a tag and then retrieve it

I have this working with the onClickListener:

```
private void AddRow(String rowNo) 
{
final TableLayout table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.my_table);
final TableRow tr = (TableRow) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.table_row_item, null);

 tr.setTag(rowNo);

 TextView tv;
  tv = (TextView) tr.findViewById(R.id.rowNo);
  tv.setText(rowNo);    

  table.addView(tr);
  tr.setOnClickListener(mClickListener);    
}
```

Then in the OnClickListener:

```
private OnClickListener mClickListener = new OnClickListener()
    {           
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
        try
            {                           
             String clickedRow = (String) v.getTag();
             Toast toast = Toast.makeText(mContext, clickedRow, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
            }
        catch (Exception ex)
            {                                   
          Toast toast = Toast.makeText(mContext, ex.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
          toast.show();         
            }

        }
    };
```

Unless I can find another solution,, I will use the same idea for the ContextMenu

The

```
- public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item)
```

doesn't have a view parameter, but

```
- public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo)
```

does,

so I guess I'll use a class level variable to store the current row in the onCreateContextMenu event and retrieve it in onContextItemSelected

Comment: The onCreateContextMenu view which is returned is the tablelayout, not the table row so that couldn't be done. I added an onLongClickListener which DOES return the row as the view and in there I set the class level rowClicked variable. Doesn't feel like the best solution but it does work